# Connecting multiple RS485 together

Tags: arduino-nano, rs485

I am trying to build communication across multiple Arduino using RS485. When i am trying to connect 3 Arudino nano together using breadboard my code doesn't reach slave where as if i just if i do direct connection between 2 RS485 without breadboard it works but i use breadboard for 2 it doesn't work. Am i missing any setup here?

Breadboard connection - A & B are connected to + & - of both RS485.

Working connection - A & B of first RS485 connected to A & B of 2nd RS485.

[image]

Comment: show a picture of the breadboard version

Answer (score 3):

It is possible you have too many resistors on the RS485 bus. From the [RS485 wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-485) there is this quote:

> Ideally, the two ends of the cable will have a termination resistor
>   connected across the two wires.

This may explain why you can use 2 of your RS485 interfaces but not 3.  Consider removing the resistors from the RS485 board in the middle if possible.

Comment: problem is even if i use only 2 with breadboard it doesn't work. It only work when i connect them directly ? Do i have to use any resistor on breadboard ?

Comment: Breadboards are not good with high frequencies.  Try slowing down the baud rate.  Also check if you are using the breadboard correctly.  So, 2 connected using wires works?  And 3 connected using wires works?  But 2 connected using the breadboard does not work?  And exactly which TTL to RS485 adapter are you using?  Have you added termination resistors to the ends of your RS485 bus?

Comment: The thing with termination resistors is, that it's value should be the wave resistance of the specific cable at that specific frequency. I don't think, that this is critical here, as long as the OP does not use too high baudrates. But the breadboard might be the real problem here.